# Convert dataframe to dataPoints in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe and want to prepare dataPoints as input for the mlib library.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
scala> preparedInput.printSchema
root
 |-- paymentID: long (nullable = false)
 |-- kategorieID: long (nullable = false)
 |-- wordIDs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)

scala> preparedInput.show
+------------+-------------+--------------------+                               
|   paymentID|  kategorieID|             wordIDs|
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 34359738421|1340029796352|[6, 13, 14, 17179...|
| 60129542192|1700807049216|[51539607552, 154...|
| 85899345934|1297080123392|[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6...|
|120259084292|1297080123392|[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...|
|128849018924|1297080123392|[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 9...|
|180388626454|  25769803785|[8589934592, 8589...|
```

I came out with the following statement, which does not work:

```
val dataPoints = preparedInput.map(row => 
    new LabeledPoint(
          "kategorieID".toDouble, 
          Vectors.parse("wordIDs")
    )
  ).cache()
```

When I use `dataPoints.show`, I will get an Exception:

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "kategorieID"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "kategorieID"` because you are invoking `toDouble` on string `kategorieID`. Please check below code.

`Vectors.parse` will only take type of `string` . 
To show you, I have used `Vectors.dense`. you can modify below code as per your use case.

```
val dataPoints = preparedInput.map { row => 
    val kategorieID = row.getAs[Long](1).toDouble
    val wordIDs = row.get(2).asInstanceOf[Seq[Long]].map(_.toDouble)
    new LabeledPoint(kategorieID,Vectors.dense(wordIDs.head,wordIDs.tail:_*))
}.cache()
```

Comment: can you tell me how to solve the typemismatch Vectors.parse(row.get(2)) -> found: Any, required: String (I have an array of doubles)

Comment: I have updated answer .. Vectors.parse will only accept string as input but row.get(2) is of type array .. for that i have used Vectors.dense .. check this.